# Create new sheets and copy data according to the ID in Master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with customers, which has the below format and is formatted as ListObject - Customer. Based on the below table, new sheets should be created as per number of customers in the Customer tab.

| Customer ID | Customer Name | Description | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer1 | John Doe | test1 | USA |
| Customer2 | Heather Novak | test2 | UK |
| Customer3 | Allison Parker | test3 | GE |

Based on the above table, 3 sheets should be created called - Customer1, Customer2 and Customer3.
These new sheets are copy of a template, which looks like this:

- blue cells are headers, which are part of the template sheet
- grey cells are blank and data from the Master sheet should be copied over as per the sheet name. I added the references of cells (it will be always the same)

[image]

The ideal output should look like this for all sheets:

[image]

I was able to create a macro, which creates sheets and named them accordingly, but I'm not able to manage transfer data from the whole row into particular cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsFromTemplate()
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet
Dim shNAMES As Range, Nm As Range

With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")                                'sheet to be copied
    Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Customers")              'sheet with names
    Set shNAMES = wsMASTER.Range("Customers[Customer ID]")  'range to find names to be checked
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Nm In shNAMES
            wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = CStr("Customer " & Nm.Text)
    Next Nm
    
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True                           'update screen one time at the end
End With

MsgBox "All sheets created"
End Sub
```

Can you advise me, how to copy and transpose data accordingly and dynamically, please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name all grey fields in the template according to their pendants in the table. Replace word spacings with an underscore (e.g. Customer_ID). Be sure to select the template not the workbook itself when naming the cells.

Then you can use the following code:

```vb
Sub SheetsFromTemplate()

Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wsCustomer As Worksheet
Dim loMaster As ListObject

With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")                                'sheet to be copied
    Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Customers")              'sheet with names
    
    Set loMaster = wsMASTER.ListObjects("Customer")
    
    Dim r As Range, Customer As String
    Dim lc As ListColumn
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each r In loMaster.DataBodyRange.Rows
        Customer = r.Cells(1, 1)
        wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        Set wsCustomer = ActiveSheet
        
        With wsCustomer
            .Name = Customer
            
            For Each lc In loMaster.ListColumns
                'Assumption: per each list column there is a named range on the sheet
                'empty spaces in column names are replaced by an underscore in range name
                .Range(Replace(lc.Name, " ", "_")) = Intersect(lc.DataBodyRange, r)
            Next
        End With
    Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True                           'update screen one time at the end
End With

MsgBox "All sheets created"
End Sub
```

The code moves through all rows of the listobject (first for-each)

Creates the new sheet per row and names it according go the first cell.

Then writes the values to each grey field by mapping the field-name to the list column names. (second for-each)

The relevant value from the customer-table is found by intersecting the listcolumn-range with the row from the first for-each-loop.